# Internet-connection not working properly on one of my computers (even after format)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, hardware-failure

All of a sudden my Internet-connection started acting strange: sites wouldn't load properly (didn't load all data, leaving the page to be unfinished, images would be strange-looking), some clients, like Steam, wouldn't find a connection at all times, youtube-videos wouldn't load.
I could always be on Skype with my friends and play WoW, though. So clearly I still had connection to the Internet. The speed of my connection is about 53 down and 11 so the speed shouldn't be any problem.

Here's two pictures showing my problem:

**Wikipedia:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERTtx.jpg] (loaded without proper layout)

**Swedish streaming site:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7BLE.png] (missed the last part of the site and two pictures are yellow-ish)

I just now finished a reinstallation of Windows 7 (I deleted ALL data that previously was on the hard drive) and still I've got the same problem.

To make sure it wasn't my WLAN reciever that was broken I threaded via both my mac and my samsung, but both with the same result. I've also made sure it isn't my router by using my phones 3G.

As I said in the title, I'm only experiencing this problem on one of my computers, so I'm beginning to think It's some problem with my hardware.

Do any off you guys have any idea what might cause this problem? I'm starting to get sooo irritated. Thank you!

Edit:
for the record I have tried Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: If a problem like this happens through multiple OS installations and multiple browsers, then the problem is the service provider, sounds like they are filtering content on you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your DNS Settings for your WiFi Adapter?

1. Right Click on the network icon and go to "Open Network and Sharing Center"
2. Click "Change Adapter Settings" on the sidebar
3. Right click the Wireless Adapter and click Properties
4. Access the IP Settings

[image]

5. At the bottom you will see an area to enter DNS Settings for the device

[image]

Simply enter the following information (These are Google Public DNS Servers):

**Preferred DNS Server:** 8.8.8.8

**Secondary DNS Server:** 8.8.4.4

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the problem stays, even after a reboot. Any other ideas? :/

Comment: @Halvurd - Contact your service provider as they are the reason this behavior happens.

Comment: I solved this issue by uninstalling my WLAN-reciver's drivers. Bridging via my mac now works perfect.